# Is there a way to block a single image (on drag or save) from the IP Address?

Tags: php, mysql

This might sound like a strange question but I think it solves my problem rather nicely. My website is made up of logos created by users, which are for sale. I'm tired of people dragging them or saving them (stealing them) and then using them.

I can prevent drags, prevent hotlinks or entering the image URL directly, and I can prevent the "save image as" feature or prevent right click altogether but then of course there is the screen shot way of getting an image.

I want to detect this abuse instantly and altogether block the single logo from the users IP address, replacing it with a message. Can this be done and what would be the best cross browser  way of accomplishing this?

So to recap, if the user right clicks a logo or attempts to drag the image off of the website, the image disappears (and cannot return to this user's IP address) and is replaced with a message, preventing them from taking the last step of taking a screen shot.

I'm not even sure if this is possible as I am not a backend developer and have not found anything close to someone asking about this.

(please refrain from telling me this doesn't solve it all because I know it doesn't. They can access another computer or steal another logo, I know. But it does show how serious we take the stealing and can prevent it that way.)

Comment: if you are afraid of copy paste then something is wrong with your business. existing successful businesses thrive in the copy paste ecosystem for years now. don't try to hold world back, it will bite you. -and what you are asking is technically possible, yet overkill.

Comment: @Sharky we have lost several clients because they tell us they found the logo being used somewhere else. It has cost us quite a bit of money

Comment: Watermark your logo's perhaps? Cause you leave still an open door for people. The printscreen button and than paste it in a image editing program. I would suggest you just simply watermark your images and just hand the ones over without watermark to your to your clients. This way, its out of your hands and you have done everything on your website to prevent it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will accompish most of the things you described:

> if the user right clicks a logo or attempts to drag the image off of
>   the website, the image disappears (and cannot return to this user's IP
>   address) and is replaced with a message, preventing them from taking
>   the last step of taking a screen shot.

add a class to your images

```
<img class="donttouchthisoriwillcrashyourbones" src="http://33.media.tumblr.com/TLJKG5e4Cebg1ni1v24quLLFo1_500.jpg">
```

then the following jquery will do what you asked.

**see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/szra2px1/42/**

```
$(".donttouchthisoriwillcrashyourbones").mousedown(function(event)
{
    if (event.which==3) 
    {
        $(this).attr("src", "http://www.pewpewpew.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/FUUUUUUUUUUU.gif");
    }
});

var leftmouseclicked = false;

$(".donttouchthisoriwillcrashyourbones").mousedown(function(event)
{
    if (event.which==1) 
    {
        leftmouseclicked=true;
    }
});

$(".donttouchthisoriwillcrashyourbones").mouseup(function(event)
{
    if (event.which==1) 
    {
        leftmouseclicked=false;
    }
});


$(".donttouchthisoriwillcrashyourbones").mousemove(function()
{
    if(leftmouseclicked)
    {
        $(this).attr("src", "http://www.pewpewpew.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/FUUUUUUUUUUU.gif");
    }
});
```

As for the IP-BAN thing, a similar approach: you can set a cookie when appropriate like

`badguy=true`

and when page loads, if `badguy=true` you can redirect him to somewhere else.

Of course all this checks are client side and can be bypassed.

Comment: Your answer cracked me up good. You get for that an upvote already. However, you should add a switch back so after a few seconds it should flip back to the original state in order to maintain your sense of bussines. And there are always people who accidently rightclick on something.

Comment: @Dorvalla There are no accidents. Only people that need to be hunted down. `setCookie("yougetnosecondchance=true")`

Comment: Hahaha that gif cracked me up!

Comment: @MichaelRader i've been in your situation, and i know the "RAGE" you are feeling when you realize that someone copies you so i knew THAT was the correct picture xD.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is impossible. As long as the image is loaded and rendered by the browser, it's already in the user's computer, so there's no 100% safe method. What you can do is add a watermark, display only a part of the images, apply a custom filter on a portion of them so they won't be usable etc.

EDIT:
Read more [here](http://css-tricks.com/techniques-for-fighting-image-theft/)

Comment: I don't think I agree. Can't AJAX alter already loaded images? Even using just JS you can quickly hide the image and make it more difficult to find. And as I said above, please refrain from saying there's no 100% method! I know!

Comment: There are two types of people when thinking this problem. Those who know web and those who don't. For those who don't, disabling right click and the other stuff that you did is enough in at least 90% of the cases. For those who know web.. the only method to prevent them from using your picture is altering the picture while still keeping a part of it original so it's a conclusive demo.

Comment: ? You don't need to know the web to take a screen shot. My grandma knows how to do that.

Comment: If you understand this, why don't you want to use an image altering method? I'm not into this, so I don't know, but what solutions did the big logo selling websites use?

Comment: Altering the image ruins the look of the logo. It is way too obtrusive.

Comment: Displaying the image in any way, even through flash, java or anything else, makes it 'vulnerable' to the prinscreen method you were concerned about earlier. You can not block the user from taking a screenshot.

Comment: @MichaelRader when you say ajax, i say something like this http://i.imgur.com/d9d6m0o.jpg

Comment: @TraianTatic I KNOW!! But hardly anybody takes a screen shot on their first attempt to steal an image. Typically they do it AFTER they have tried to simply save it.

Comment: @MichaelRader have you ever thought the possibility that a POTENTIAL CLIENT wants to save the image to his computer?

Comment: @Sharky yes I did but I don't think this is often the case. And I don't get your image, sry.

Comment: @MichaelRader the image says that if you implement an ajax protection system that needs to be online in order to work, someone can just load your website, close the internet and then copy everything. it's a funny picture.

Comment: @Sharky again, I KNOW THIS IS NOT 100% AFFECTIVE! What you're saying is what someone who is VERY web savvy would do, which most of our visitors are not.

Comment: Well, in this case, if this is what you want, just give access to the link of the full size image. On that full link, display an alert message just before the image loads with "You are not allowed to view this image, please close the tab or click 'Cancel'" (and the user should be redirected back) but in case he clicks 'Ok, I still want to see the image', you can ban his ip.

Comment: Just to throw this in here, when I want to use an image from a (royalty free) website, I'll print screen first, as then I can simply paste the page in Photoshop and crop